# Binding a objC with RoboVM in Java

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, libgdx, robovm

Hey I vitally need microphone access in my IOS app that I am making with libGDX and RoboVM. I read that I can bind a objC Class to a Java class. I read the documentation at https://github.com/robovm/robovm/wiki/The-Bro-Java-to-native-bridge However I am unable to make heads or tails of it.

So I have my mic.h and mic.m class files, however how do I bind these to Java functions? All I need is to get a meter rating.

Thanks! :)

-edit- If its important the mic class has two public functions init and read

Comment: If there is an easier way, please let me know :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote a blog answering my own question lol
here it is:

http://www.sevenarmedsquid.com/help/robovmbinding

Comment: This link is old, and I'd sure like to know the answer.

Comment: The link is not only old but broken. OP, will you summarise your solution in an SO answer?

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20150109223825/http://www.sevenarmedsquid.com/help/robovmbinding